# i keep getting this error and i don't know why

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

here is the error

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/ai-chat.py"
  File "/Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/ai-chat.py", line 38
    with open ('Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/RC_2015-01.txt⁩' buffering=1000) as f:
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.051 seconds
```

here is my code

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sqlite3
import json
from datetime import datetime

timeframe = '2015-05'
sql_transaction = []

connection = sqlite3.connect('{}.db'.format(timeframe))
c = connection.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply(parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, parent TEXT, comment TEXT, subreddit TEXT, unix INT, score INT)")

def format_data(data):
    data = data.replace('\n',' newlinechar ').replace('\r',' newlinechar ').replace('"',"'")
    return data

def find_parent(pid):
    try:
        sql = "SELECT comment FROM parent_reply WHERE comment_id = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pid)
        c.execute(sql)
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result != None:
            return result[0]
        else: return False
    except Exception as e:
        #print(str(e))
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table()
    row_counter = 0
    paired_rows = 0


    with open ('Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/RC_2015-01.txt⁩' buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            row_counter += 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            score = row['score']
            comment_id = row['name']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']
            parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                create_table()
                row_counter = 0
                paired_rows = 0
            # maybe check for a child, if child, is our new score superior? If so, replace. If not...

            if score >= 2:
                existing_comment_score = find_existing_score(parent_id)
```

Comment: `except Exception as e:` is bad practice. You should test if a variable is `None` using `is None` or `is not None`, not `==`. Please fix the formatting of your code, it isn't even clear to me if the issue is with Stack Overflow's formatting or the program itself.

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```
with open('Cloud Drive⁩/Desktop/chat/RC_2015-01.txt⁩', buffering=1000) as f:
```

instead of

```
with open ('Cloud Drive⁩/Desktop/chat/RC_2015-01.txt⁩' (buffering=1000)) as f:
```

What you had is not valid syntax.

Comment: now i get this [Running] python -u "/Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/ai-chat.py"
  File "/Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/ai-chat.py", line 38
    with open ('Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/RC_2015-01.txt⁩' buffering=1000) as f:
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.051 seconds

Comment: @mciver9010 You're missing the comma after the string and before `buffering`.  Follow the example in the answer exactly, and you should get it.

Comment: now its saying   [Running] python -u "/Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/ai-chat.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/ai-chat.py", line 38, in <module>
    with open ('Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/RC_2015-01.txt⁩', buffering=1000) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/thomasmciver/Desktop/chat/RC_2015-01.txt\xe2\x81\xa9'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.084 seconds

Comment: @mciver9010, we're not here to hold your hand until all of your errors are fixed. You asked a question and got what appears to be a helpful answer. That should be the end of it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Read your new error messages carefully and see if you can figure out the problem. (Hint: this one says it can't find your file. Look carefully at the path it's looking for. Does it look right?) If you can't figure it out by yourself, search for existing similar questions. If that doesn't do it feel free to ask a new question. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].